# c++ Save output (numbers) into an array. Two numbers at a time

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, integer, output

Here's what I need to do:
 - user inputs some capital letters or words,
 - I turn around these letters (which I did with "obrjen") 
 - I transform those letters to ASCII values, 
 - I multiply all of those numbers with 4, 
 - I save the value and output it. Than I will do the same, but vise-versa to make a decrypt and get back the words

Any help is appriciated, thanks!

```
void sifriraj(char sifra[100], char obrjen[100], int &velikost3)
{
        int j=99;
            for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
                obrjen[j]=sifra[i];
                j--;
                for (i; i>99-velikost3 && i<100; i++)
                {
                if (obrjen[i]==' ')
                {
                    cout<<"00";
                }
                if (obrjen[i]=='A')
                {
                    cout<<"65";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='B')
                {
                    cout<<"66";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='C')
                {
                    cout<<"67";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='D')
                {
                    cout<<"68";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='E')
                {
                    cout<<"69";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='F')
                {
                    cout<<"70";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='G')
                {
                    cout<<"71";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='H')
                {
                    cout<<"72";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='I')
                {
                    cout<<"73";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='J')
                {
                    cout<<"74";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='K')
                {
                    cout<<"75";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='L')
                {
                    cout<<"76";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='M')
                {
                    cout<<"77";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='N')
                {
                    cout<<"78";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='O')
                {
                    cout<<"79";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='P')
                {
                    cout<<"80";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='R')
                {
                    cout<<"82";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='S')
                {
                    cout<<"83";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='T')
                {
                    cout<<"84";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='U')
                {
                    cout<<"85";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='V')
                {
                    cout<<"86";
                }
                else if (obrjen[i]=='Z')
                {
                    cout<<"90";
                }

                }
            }
            cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: if your code to print a line of numbers is 1200 lines, then maybe you should first fix this code before adding more functionality

Comment: The program is made for 17 different functions. (a project)
Sorry for not stating this before. The program is not only to print a line.

Comment: To help you one does not need to see the whole project, but what is necessary is to see howyou store these numbers. That you print them on the screen at some point is rather irrelevant

Comment: I don't store them in any way. They are simply cout'ed.
And I need to save this cout's to some array or something.

Comment: show the code or it didnt happen

Comment: @S-K Please read how to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Edited the post and included the whole Void.
I enter some word (example: stack) and it prints out the numbers.
Now I need to multiply these numbers by 4.

Comment: You missed the fact that you can `static_cast` `obrjen[i]` to `int` to get the ASCII value.

Comment: @LogicStuff I'm sorry mate.. I'm not an advanced programmer...

Is there any way to use my code and save those numbers?

Comment: And if you have to continue your calculations with these numbers, just store them. Actually, you already have them stored, you can perform calculations on `char`s, too. They are integral types!

Answer (score 0):

To get the ascii code from a char you simply have to do this:

```
char x = 'A';
int  a = x;
std::cout << x << " has ascii code " << a;
```

Thus, as LogicStuff commented, you already have those numbers stored and you can use them for later calculations.

Comment: Thank you.
result.push_back(0);?
What do I put instead of this in 'A'?

And yes, I do know that there will always be 2 numbers a time.

Comment: `result.push_back(65)`

Comment: Ohh.. right. Thanks mate!
Shouldn't there be result.push_back(00); instead of result.push_back(0);?
Since I need to have a value of "00"?

Comment: But dont do this! I missed the whole point, that these numbers are the ascii values.

Comment: @S-K what is the value of `00` as a number?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to cast them. Any idea what to do than?

Comment: If there is an output "00" it means space --> " "

Comment: @S-K udated the answer

Comment: Thanks mate.
But I still have to ask, is there any way to just save the output my code generates and than read it two numbers by two?

Comment: @S-K why do you want to do this?

Comment: As I understand it the best, I don't quite understand those casts and strings and stuff yet. Didn't get to that point yet :/

Comment: you dont understand `char x; int a = x;` ? Then try to understand it. It will be easier than any other solution

Comment: Yes, but how do I implement this into my code? and how can I use them later?
Sorry for stupidity..

Comment: There is nothing you have to implement yourself. Sorry, I dont really understand what part you dont understand. You have a array of chars `obrjen` and if you want to e.g. add ascii code of letter at pos `i` with letter at pos `j` it is simply: `int result = obrjen[i] + obrjen[j]`.

Comment: I understand that, but if I use your code for space " " it won't give me "00", right? because that's not the ASCII value for space?

Comment: the ascii value for space is 32. Do you really need to map space to "00" ??

Comment: Well.. I can change that to 32 yeah.. Thanks mate, I'll try to do this.
So I need to give each charather a 'int', right? and it will return me those values.

How do I use those values later? I will have to multiply all of them by 4.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It would really help if you say **what** is your aim and not **how** you want to get there.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Here's the whole proccess I want to do:
- user inputs some capital letters or words,
- I turn around these letters (which I did with "obrjen")
- I transform those letters to ASCII values,
- I multiply all of those numbers with 4,
- I save the value and output it.

Than I will do the same, but vise-versa to make a decrypt and get back the words

Comment: why didnt you ask this question? I dont want to edit my answer, because it would not fit the original question and its too long for a comment

Comment: I will update the question right now mate. Thank you for the help and again, sorry for my stupidity

EDIT: Updated!

Comment: @S-K well  maybe not too long for a comment. `std::vector<int> encrypt(char in[N]){std::vector<int> result;for (int i=0;i<N;i++){result.push_back(in[i]*4);}return result;}` and `std::vector<char> decrypt(std::vector<int> in){std::vector<char> result;for (int i=0;i<N;i++){result.push_back(in[i]/4);}return result;}`

Comment: @S-K and please dont edit the question. It would change its meaning completely and there are already answer, that adress your original question. Even one that shows you how to parse a string the way you were asking for. You could ask a new question

Comment: Already edited it :/ sorry..
Back to point:
You showed me full code for both?
That's what I need to do. First code for encrypt and second for decrypt, right?

Comment: @S-K yes, you need the `int`s to avoid overflow from the multiplications, otherwise you could stay with `char`s only

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will get it to work now. 
Thanks again!

Comment: @S-K good that it helped, but for next time please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Solving problems in comments won`t help anybody but you (which somehow defeats the concept of SO) and also it can be annoying when you write an answer just to realize that the question was edits such that the answer does not fit anymore (not complaining for me, but imho Ujjwal gave a nice answer, that adresses what you originally were asking for, but now it doesnt really fit anymore)

Comment: Yes, thank you and sorry for that. Will do all different next time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that now you posted a code in your question by editing it. The code seems to be some ASCII extraction. You simply need to extract each charcter and stream it through an extraction operator into a `int` variable.

Previously it seemed that you have a string of numbers which you want to parse two at a time. Thus the following code, which no longer applies in your position.

Consider this code :

It takes a `std::string` and parses the string two characters at a time saved as an unsigned int, into a `std::vector`. You can output the numbers in the line as a string and feed it to this function.

```
vector<unsigned int>get_num(string& str)
{
        string::iterator it{str.begin()};
        string::iterator it_end{str.end()};
        vector<unsigned int> out_vector;
        unsigned int val{};
        while(it<it_end)
        {
                string part(it,it+2);
                it+=2;
                istringstream reader(part);
                reader>>val;
                out_vector.push_back(val);
        }
        return out_vector;
}
```

Comment: and why should he do this? Please look at the OPs code. Even if the question/title suggests otherwise, he does not need to do any parsing.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand this code (I'm stilla beginner), thus I don't feel comfortable using it :/

Comment: @tobi303 : Oh, so now he posted a code. I wrote this code before refreshing the page. Seems he edited the question. It seems he is doing some kind of ASCII extraction there. In that case your answer seems perfect and simplest. I originally thought he is simply looking to parse  a string of numbers , two characters at a time.

Comment: Thanks mate, I did edit the question with code later yes. Thank you for help